# imacros not working in firefox properly

Tags: javascript, firefox, imacros

I have .iim file in iMacros and when I Play it in firefox few text fields are not extracted but same .iim file is working in iMacros software .

I am using Firefox because I can see .js(java-script file) in firefox.Is there any other way to see .js file in iMacros software also why the text extracted in firefox is not working for a few field ??

Please help me out .Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iMacros browser support several more commands and options, which imacros for firefox does not support - this may be the issues.
You can view .js files using any text editor software, even notepad.

Comment: Fill us in on what several more commands are those ? I know for image recognition but what else ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.I finally figured it out.I used to check in the csv sheet and there was a blank in the columns above and assume that it was empty (even if I expand it) but when I clicked on wrap text above I started to see the text .But I still couldn't click on the individual text ,I guess I need to remove blank spaces before and after.Finally the problem is solved .Thanks again for the support.Have a good day.